# How can I solve this error with load data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv

I'm trying to upload a csv into a mysql db, but i've this error and I dont know why.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 1

Here is my query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'india_agriculture_company.csv' 
INTO TABLE india_agriculture_company (name,url,logo,founder,inception_year,key_products,coverage,revenue,value_chain) 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column list -- alas -- does not follow the table name.  Try this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'india_agriculture_company.csv' 
INTO TABLE india_agriculture_company  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(name, url, logo, founder, inception_year, key_products, coverage, revenue, value_chain);
```

I find this counter-intuitive as well.  I think I always write this code the wrong way the first time.